# Display contents of array after using Underscore.js "groupBy" function

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have a set of data that I want to group by Month:

```
var data = [
    {WT: 'Brick', Month: 'January', Weight: '50'},
    {WT: 'Brick', Month: 'January', Weight: '55'},
    {WT: 'Metal', Month: 'January', Weight: '150'},
    {WT: 'Paper', Month: 'March', Weight: '10'},
    {WT: 'Paper', Month: 'March', Weight: '12'},
]
```

And so far, I have this code which groups it all by month:

```
var groupedCo2 = _.groupBy(data, 'Month');
```

However, I now need to add all of the `Weight` values together and group them together by the `WT` value. When I do `console.log` for the `groupedCo2` var, I see the months and the remaining data contained inside them, but every time I try to display the contained information I either get `object` error message or `undefined`.

How, using underscore.js, can I access the variables once the data has been initially grouped?

***EDIT***
The data Structure I'm looking for is this in pseudo fashion:

```
var data = [
    {
        Month: 'January' 
        {
            WT: 'Brick',
            Weight: '50'
        }
    }
]
```

This should, I think, allow me to have a inner loop to count up the weight and to group it by weight when it's initially grouped by Month.

Comment: Please correct the result you need, because what you have wrote here is not a correct object structure

Comment: I've amended it as best I can. I haven't used JQuery like this before, so I'm unsure as to how I would write a multidimensional array in JQuery.

Comment: you can either do `Month:{ ... }` or `'January':{ ... }`

Comment: I would but there could be any number of months, it won't be static.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for the sum of Weight grouped by Month, then by WT? If so, it would look something like this...

```
var groupedData = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('Month')
    .map(function (group, key) {
    return {
        Month: key,
        WTs: _.chain(group)
            .groupBy("WT")
            .map(function (group, key) {
            return {
                WT: key,
                TotalWeight: _.reduce(group, function(memo, i){ 
                    return memo + parseInt(i.Weight, 10); 
                }, 0)
            };
        })
        .value()
    }})
    .value();
```

The result is:

```
[
    {
        "Month": "January",
        "WTs": [
            {
                "WT": "Brick",
                "TotalWeight": 105
            },
            {
                "WT": "Metal",
                "TotalWeight": 150
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Month": "March",
        "WTs": [
            {
                "WT": "Paper",
                "TotalWeight": 22
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And you could loop through it like this:

```
_.each(groupedData, function(m) {
    console.log("Month: ", m.Month);
    _.each(m.WTs, function(wt) {
        console.log("  ", wt.WT,  ": ", wt.TotalWeight);
    });
});
```

Which outputs:

```
Month:  January
   Brick :  105
   Metal :  150
Month:  March
   Paper :  22
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrx3k/)

Comment: This is brilliant, it's more or less what I wanted to achieve. Only issue I seem to have is that it seems to be rounding the numbers down (some data use decimals - 0.47 for example).

Comment: Try changing `parseInt(i.Weight, 10)` to `parseFloat(i.Weight)`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I've looked at the console.log and it does indeed display the information I need. Just need to get it working nicely with Flot.js now!